# Why is egg and orange juice such a bad combo?

Tags: eggs, juice, oranges

Eggs and orange juice are not uncommon around the breakfast table, but unfortunately, eating and drinking both in the same mouthful was an unpleasant surprise.

It was as if a chemical reaction had created a third foul taste that was nothing like the two ingredients. My untrained tongue can only describe it as bitter.

#### Update 1:

**I wonder why the combination doesn't taste like the sum of its parts;** this combination specifically.

#### Update 2:

Use your imagination! Human perception is merely the null hypothesis (obviously uninteresting), so I'm really asking this: **Is there something more to it** than that? First of all, **is this a chemical reaction, or is it not?**

Example answers:

- *Oh boy, this is a chemical reaction! Eggs contain sulfur, and oranges contain E300 (acid you know) so this becomes sulfuric acid! That's why.*
- *The acidic solution breaks down the egg much like stomac juice, releasing H<sub>2</sub>S, which tastes rotten. That's why.*
- *The acid + your spit makes instant biodiesel out of the fats in the egg. Beat that!*
- *Sad to disappoint you, but nothing special is going on with this mixture. Your tongue tricked you.*

Comment: I have some trouble finding an answerable question here. Are you wondering why the combination doesn't taste like the sum of its parts? This is true of all things we taste, the brain creates a unique perception for everything it senses (and that combination is unique for each person and context). Are you wondering why you didn't like the combination? This is not answerable, it is literally a matter of taste. Are you wondering why your brain picked the label "bitter" when you wondered how to describe the taste? This is also not answerable, another person would have picked something else.

Comment: Maybe you perceive the taste of egg in a very sour environment as spoiled?

Comment: Hi, I saw the edit. No sensory input is ever perceived as the sum of its parts, and the "why" is an explanation of how human senses work - a very interesting area, but it is basic neurology+psychology and has little to do with cooking. Your question basically amounts to "how does human perception work".

Comment: We also have compounds that block or modify our taste buds.  Something in toothpaste mutes our sense of sweetness, so orange juice is then horribly out of balance.

Comment: It's a fair question, it didn't seem opinion based to me - there are reactions that occur and perceptions that are common with certain combinations of ingredients, and no way to know if this specific mixture was one of them or not before asking.  There may be a chemical reaction or may not, a common effect or not, but that is a question that can be asked (especially since "no known reason" is listed as an acceptable potential answer)

Comment: @GdD: Reopen? It's not opinion based – please see Update 2. Thanks.

Comment: @user2394284 Maybe the title and motivation for the question should be changed in light of your last edit. Something along the lines of "Is there a chemical reaction between eggs and orange juice that causes foul taste?"

Comment: Even with the edit, your question remains hard to answer. There are probably dozens of chemical reactions going on there - I doubt that somebody has even listed all chemicals contained in an orange. Trying to name one as the cause of your dislike would be pure speculation. Also, you still seem to believe in the false dichotomy of "chemical reaction" vs "tongue tricking you".